# Laplace Transform (Voltage Transformation)

Tags: voltage, laplace-transform

So I was solving some circuits with the use of Voltage Transformation and Laplace Transform and I came up with this circuit. I'm not sure how to solve for 
IL and IC.

R3 and V1 are the voltage transformation of a 2H inductor while R4 and V2 are
the voltage transformation of a 1/2 F capacitor.

By observation, I think it would be easier to choose nodal analysis.
However, I'm not sure how to properly arrange the components to limit the number
of nodes/equations needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0mWzq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No Homework questions here please.. Try to solve the question, and if you're unable to proceed at some point, this forum could be of help then.

Comment: You can use either node or mesh analysis. You will need the same number of equations to find the same number of unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

To be solved by Laplace transforms, the entire circuit must be in the frequency domain.  Therefore I2 must be represented by 2/(S+1).  The 4 for V1 states that Il=2A at t=0+.  When the topological graph is drawn for the circuit (opening current sources and shorting voltage sources), there is only one loop around which to write a mesh equation which is: (2/s)Ic+(2S)Il+Ir2+3Ir1=4-4/S; where Ir2 is the downward current in R2. Along with ancillary equations relating the various currents, we finally get:  Il=(2S^2+5S+2)/(S+1)^3.  Using partial fraction expansion and taking the inverse Laplace transform we get:
i(t)=[(-1/2)t^2 + t + 2)]e^-t).  As a check, evaluating at t=0+, we get il(0+)=2 which is expected.